# How do I move all subfolders in one directory to another folder in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory, subdirectory

I have a directory with folders and files, and I want to move all the folders into another folder that's inside the directory.

I already can move all the files in the directory(Not including the files in the subfolders), but I am also trying to figure out how to move the subfolders.

```
string selectedDrive = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

```
            string folderName = selectedDrive + @"\\Encrypted"; // Creates a directory under the selected drive.

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
            string moveTo = (selectedDrive + @"\Encrypted");
```

```
            String [] allFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(selectedDrive); //Should return folder 

            foreach (String Folder in allFolders)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(moveTo + Folder))
                {
                    FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Folder, moveTo);
                }

            }
```

Instead, I have an error at this line `FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Folder, moveTo);`
saying the following: `System.IO.IOException: 'Could not complete operation since source directory and target directory are the same.'`

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? It's telling you that you can't move (assuming C) C:\Encrypted to C:\Encrypted. That makes sense.

Comment: I just realized that I ignored the error message(LoL), and I came up with this code:
                    if (Folder != moveTo)

Also, my homedrive is actually not C:\, it's F:\, and the Drive that I am using is a flash drive called E:\.

Comment: The code I came up with does not work and I am experiencing the same error.

Comment: How do I resolve this?

Comment: I just figured out that the Folder string is actually a file.

Comment: It's still not working, even thoughI KNOW it's not moving E:\Encrypted to E:\Encrypted. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Which version of NET are you using? NET6 or still the Framwork 4.x?

Comment: Hi, Steve. I am using 4.x. More specifically, 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reworked your code to make it work in this way:

```
// source of copies, but notice the endslash, it's required 
// if you use the string replace method below
string selectedDrive = @"E:\temp\";  

string destFolderName = Path.Combine(selectedDrive, "Encrypted");
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolderName);

// All folders except the one just created
var allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(selectedDrive)
                          .Except(new[] { destFolderName });

// Loop over the sources
foreach (string source in allFolders)
{
    // this line in framework 4.8, 
    string relative = source.Replace(selectedDrive, "");

    // or this line if using NET Core 6
    // string relative = Path.GetRelativePath(selectedDrive, source));

    // Create the full destination name
    string dest = Path.Combine(destFolderName, relative);


    if (!Directory.Exists(dest))
    {
        FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, dest);
    }

}
```

Also noted now that you are using a root drive (F:) as source for the directories to copy. In this case you should consider that you have other folders not accessible or not copy-able. (For example the Recycle.bin folder). However you can easily add other exclusions to the array passed to the IEnumerable extension `Except`

```
....
.Except(new[] { destFolderName, "Recycle.bin" });
```

Comment: This didn't work at first, but after several tweaks here and there, it finally worked. Thanks very much.